# How do I return the subsite Link URL for each subsite? Right now, it only displays the title of each subsite

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs

[image]
This is what I have so far to basically get all of the subsites but I cannot find a way to link each subsite to it's own subsite url.

Comment: try it as `subsiteValue += "<span>" + site.Title + "</span><a href=" + site.ServerRelativeUrl + "></a><br/>";`

Comment: Tried it but no luck. But I was able to get the full url this time. I am trying to now link create a "a href" link around it. subsiteValue += site.Title + "</br>" + "mysite"+ site.ServerRelativeUrl + "<br/>";

Comment: mysite is just the intranet site link such as mysite.com

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you need a URL of all Sub Sites.
may be this will be helpful.

```
$.ajax({
    url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetSubwebsFilteredForCurrentUser(nWebTemplateFilter=-1)?filter=WebTemplate",
        method:"GET", headers:{
        "Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success:function(data){
        if(data.d.results.length>0)
        {
            var subSites = data.d.results;

            var subisteurlArray=$.map(subSites,function(o){return window.location.origin + o.ServerRelativeUrl})
            console.log(subisteurlArray);
            var subsiteValue = "<h2> Subsites </h2><br/>";
            $.each(subisteurlArray,function(i,o){
                subsiteValue+= o + " <br/>";
            });
            if($('#outputInfo').length>0)
                $('#outputInfo').html(subsiteValue);
            console.log(subsiteValue);
        }

        console.log(subSites);
    },
    error:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below code snippet. It lists all the subsites and links each subsite to its own url:

```
<div id="outputInfo"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>​​<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetSubwebsFilteredForCurrentUser(nWebTemplateFilter=-1)?filter=WebTemplate",
            method:"GET", headers:{
            "Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success:function(data){
            var subSites = data.d.results;
            console.log(subSites);
            var subsiteValue = "<h2> Subsites</h2><br/>";
            subSites.forEach(function(site){
                subsiteValue += "<a target='_blank' href=" + site.ServerRelativeUrl + ">" + site.Title + "</a><br/>";
            });
            $('#outputInfo').html(subsiteValue);
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. I had a hard time generating the link but yeah this is it!

Comment: Is there a way to only display these subsites based on user access? I thought GetSubwebsFilteredForCurrentUser would display only subsites based on if a user has access to that subsite.